# Number of copies of instance method and fields?

Tags: c#, .net, object, memory

Just being curious.

If I create 2 objects of a particular class, then 2 instances of the instance methods and the instance variables are present in the memory for that particular class?

EDIT: I tried with `static` and for sure, only one instance of the members were there but not sure with instance variables though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create 2 objects of a particular class, then 2 instances of the instance methods and the instance variables are present in the memory for that particular class?

Instance fields - yes.  Instance methods (including property accessors), no.  Code (both instance and static) is shared among all instances.

Note that static classes will create an additional *type* for each generic parameter used, and each of those types will share one set of static variables, so for example:

```
// for example only, not intended to be a perfect singleton implementation
public class Singleton<T> where t : new()
{
    private static T _Instance;

    public T Instance()
    {
        return _Instance ?? (_Instance = new T());
    }
}
```

`Singleton<Class1>` and `Singleton<Class2>` will each have a *different* object in memory for `_Instance`.

Comment: @D Stanley: Great one liner explanation. Thanks a lot. Just one more clarification: For static fields and methods, there is only copy right?

Comment: Yes - but see my edit for a caveat on generic types.